# How to check if a random number is in a certain range?

Tags: julia

I want to check if the first number of a certain random sequence is in the range -1 < x < 1  where `x` is the number I want to check.

Take for example,

```
A = [-20.665,1.334,0.112,-2.334]
```

How can we find that A[1] is in -1 < A[1] < 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple. You just write

```
if -1 < A[1] < 1
    # everything is awesome
else
    # something is wrong
end
```

This works because chained comparisons are allowed in Julia (just like in Python)

Comment: A small note is that it is good to know the `first` function. `A[1]` may be problematic if  1) a sequence is not indexable or 2) `1` is not a first element of the sequence. `first` will work for any iterable.